# Building a chart with imported data from another sheet gives error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro to buil a chart that gets error 1004 when using a table in one sheet filled with data imported from a different sheet. It works fine when I use exactly the same table but created manually in the current sheet. This is my code. Can I have some help?

```
Sub MacroChart()
    'Copy data from "Sheet1" to Sheet2
    'Copying column by column because I read somewhere that it may solve the problem.
    'Unfortunatly, not.
    n = 3
    While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1) <> ""
        n = n + 1
    Wend
    n = n - 1
    'I need to skip column B
    from1 = "A3:A" & n
    from2 = "C3:C" & n
    from3 = "D3:D" & n
    from4 = "E3:E" & n
    from5 = "F3:F" & n
    n = n - 2
    to1 = "A1:A" & n
    to2 = "B1:B" & n
    to3 = "C1:C" & n
    to4 = "D1:D" & n
    to5 = "E1:E" & n
    'The current table will have 5 columns and 54 lines, all cells filled
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range(to1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(from1).Value
        .Range(to2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(from2).Value
        .Range(to3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(from3).Value
        .Range(to4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(from4).Value
        .Range(to5).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(from5).Value
    End With
    area = "$A$1:$E$" & n

    'Creating the chart
    'The code stops on line "FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType..."
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(area)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Think you'll have to use .Item(1) after .FullSeriesCollection, and then don't specify a number on  .FullSeriesCollection, like .FullSeriesCollection.Item(i)

Comment: Thank you Alex 4336 for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.Item()` after `.FullSeriesCollection` and there is an easier method to calculate last row :

```
Sub MacroChart()
Dim n As Long, _
    wS1 As Worksheet, _
    ws2 As Worksheet, _
    Area As String, _
    cH As Chart, _
    Sh as Shape
    'Copy data from "Sheet1" to Sheet2
    'Copying column by column because I read somewhere that it may solve the problem.
    'Unfortunatly, not.
    Set wS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    n = wS1.Range("A" & wS1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'I need to skip column B
    from1 = "A3:A" & n
    from2 = "C3:C" & n
    from3 = "D3:D" & n
    from4 = "E3:E" & n
    from5 = "F3:F" & n

    n = n - 2
    to1 = "A1:A" & n
    to2 = "B1:B" & n
    to3 = "C1:C" & n
    to4 = "D1:D" & n
    to5 = "E1:E" & n
    'The current table will have 5 columns and 54 lines, all cells filled
    With ws2
        .Range(to1).Value = wS1.Range(from1).Value
        .Range(to2).Value = wS1.Range(from2).Value
        .Range(to3).Value = wS1.Range(from3).Value
        .Range(to4).Value = wS1.Range(from4).Value
        .Range(to5).Value = wS1.Range(from5).Value
    End With
    Area = "$A$1:$E$" & n

    'Creating the chart
    'The code stops on line "FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType..."
    Set Sh = ws2.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
    Set cH = Sh.Chart
    With cH
        .SetSourceData Source:=w2.Range(Area)
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(1).AxisGroup = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(2).AxisGroup = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(3).ChartType = xlLine
        .FullSeriesCollection.Item(3).AxisGroup = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you R3uK for your help on this matter and the clue to improve my coding.
I used your code. It stops on line:
Set cH = ws2.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)
Error message: Run-time error 13: type mismatch
However: Dim cH As Chart
What could be wrong?

Comment: try to `dim Sh as Shape` and change `ch` to `sh` in the line, and then `set ch = sh.chart`, I seem to remember I already encountered that

Comment: I’m sorry to come again with my problem. When using the code with the data copied from the other sheet it stops exactly on the same line as before: .FullSeriesCollection.Item(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered. However I tried again to use the table with the data added manually and the code runs OK. It creates the chart as expected. I presume that the Excel routine to build this type of chart is facing a problem of internal addressing procedures that are not present when the data is not coming from elsewhere. This is far from my basic knowledge. I hope you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: @vir.2000 : Strange indeed... I can't get my head around that... Have you tried to paste the data manually and define `Area` manually to test the last part of code? And what is the error that you have with the programmatic copy?

Comment: Hi R3uK. The macro code stops at line: .FullSeriesCollection.Item(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered with error 1004. The odd thing is that when creating exactly the same table with manual inputs, there is no error and the chart is built as expected. (I need to say more but the space do not allows).

Comment: The error occurs when the data is transferred programmatically or manually by copy and paste. That is, when it comes from elseware. It runs OK only when the data is written by hand.

Comment: I made several tests with no result: using other sheets or modifying the cells formatting. I also tested building the chat in the sheet where the data is but coping it to different cells with no success. You may questioning: why do I not try to build the chart getting the data directly from the original cells? The reason is because I don’t know how to use non adjacent columns to build the chart. The original table has columns from A to F and I want to skip column B. Nevertheless, the 1004 error is a mystery. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Do you have any formulas in your initial values? And you may create the graph from the initial source and then delete the serie that use column B, I don't how to this by heart but you may be able to find the source range in a property (use F2 in VBE to see Object Browser and fin the one) of the serie, so that you can choose which serie to delete! ;)

Comment: I’m lost in the object browser window. I still have much of VBA to learn. Back to the charts building problem, the data I’m using does not include formulas. I’m doing more experiments and notice that if I create a new table in a new workbook and a macro to build a chart, at first the code runs OK but stops with error 1004 on further modifications. The modifications consist in copping and pasting the table to some columns aside on the same sheet and modifying the range in the code accordingly...

Comment: I insisted in this approach because the data I use in my application has been copied programmatically from other places. It seems that occurs some sort of a memory effect that upsets the application when the data that I use derive from other places. If it is so, then it is kept registered for ever once the problem persists after closing and reopening the application. Many thanks.